# Not Able to update records using jdbctemplate, using with Spring batch in write step

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to update few rows using some condition in write step.i used jdbcTemplate for that.when I have debug jdbctemplate.Update() returning number of rows updated but it is not reflect in Database.
 not clear what might be reason

Here is sample code for this:-

```
class Test implements ItemWriter<Object> {
private void update(){
    String sql = update table set tid='235185642' 
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
}
 private void createGroup(List<? extends Object> list){
 //some opeartion on list
for(Object obj :list)
    update();
}

//This method is spring batch write method will write at once 
@Override
public void write(List<? extends Object> list) throws Exception {
  createGroup(list);
  //write in batch
   updateGrouping();
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: just don't create a new transaction inside current one, let it save all or nothing

Comment: i'm not sure first transaction even created, it was just guessing that as writer spring batch calling my method